# Modify global texture3d variable in HLSL

Tags: directx, shader, hlsl

How would I go about making a global texture3d variable which I can modify in the geometry shader (HLSL)?

The size would be 64x64x64.

I would fill it up once in the first renderpass and use it in the second renderpass.

Any help appreciated. Preferably using D10.

EDIT:

I'm making a marching cube terrain shader by following this https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch01.html guide (See paragraph 1.4). I got the geometry shader done it's just that I don't have normals and the guide suggests that I can create them by storing data in texture3D but I don't know how I can put data in a texture3D. (The guide is using DX10).

Comment: Maybe this would help, the GS version should work in DX10 as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124668/rendering-to-a-full-3d-render-target-in-one-pass/29544276#29544276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably thinking of a compute shader. In this case, you would declare your texture as an [RWTexture3D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471511(v=vs.85).aspx) in the compute shader, and then sample it in your render pass as a Texture3D. There are many resources/tutorials/examples on the internet about compute shaders to help you get started.

You cannot modify textures with a geometry shader in D3D11. The only thing that a [geometry shader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509609(v=vs.85).aspx) can do is generate primitives. However, as @Adam Miles answer states, it is possible to write the RWTexture3D in a geometry shader in D3D11.1. While this is feasible, unless you are also generating primitives with your geometry shader, it probably makes most sense to do it in a compute shader.

If you are working in D3D 10.x via the D3D11 API, you can still use [compute shaders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), although you cannot use an `RWTexture3D` type. You would have to view it as an `RWByteAddressBuffer`, and index it yourself which would be slightly awkward. You don't necessarily need to generate texture data within a shader, you can write into the texture with the CPU, by mapping it and writing the data directly. See [ID3D10Texture3D::Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173873(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is there no way to do this in directx10? I'm making a marching cube terrain shader by following this http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch01.html guide (See paragraph 1.4). I got the geometry shader done it's just that I don't have normals and the guide suggests that I can create them by storing data in texture3D but I don't know how I can put data in a texture3D. (The guide is also using DX10).

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to support Direct3D 11.1 cards and above you **can** achieve what it is you're asking using an RWTexture3D, contrary to the other answer.

You're free to bind a 64x64x64 RWTexture3D to the Geometry Shader stage and write to it in the same way you would in a Compute Shader.

See [Use UAVs at every pipeline stage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#use_uavs_at_every_pipeline_stage) for what's now possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is there no way to do this in directx10? I'm making a marching cube terrain shader by following this http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch01.html guide (See paragraph 1.4). I got the geometry shader done it's just that I don't have normals and the guide suggests that I can create them by storing data in texture3D but I don't know how I can put data in a texture3D. (The guide is also using DX10).